# Given the following matrix $M$, how can I find an equation for $M^n$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-exponential

> Given the following matrix $M$, find an equation for $M^n$
>
> $$M = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 &  0  & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 1 &0 \\ 0 & 0& 0& 1 \\ 1& 0& 0& 0\end{pmatrix}$$

I’ve got as far as establishing that $n+1$ moves each $1$ entry a step to the right, but how do you translate this into an equation?

Notes :

\begin{align}M^2 &= \begin{pmatrix}0& 0& 1& 0 \\ 0& 0& 0& 1 \\ 1& 0& 0& 0 \\ 0& 1& 0& 0\end{pmatrix}\\
M^3 &= \begin{pmatrix}0& 0& 0& 1 \\ 1& 0& 0& 0 \\ 0& 1& 0& 0 \\ 0& 0& 1& 0\end{pmatrix}\\
M^4 &= \begin{pmatrix}1& 0& 0& 0 \\ 0& 1& 0& 0 \\ 0& 0& 1& 0 \\ 0& 0& 0& 1\end{pmatrix}\end{align}

Comment: How about trying $M^5$? Do you notice that it starts repeating itself?

Comment: You can use `mod`.  $(M^k)_{r,c} = \begin{cases}1&\text{if}~r-c+k\equiv 0\pmod{4}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.  I've probably gotten a sign or two wrong but that gives you the idea.  Massage it until it works correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $M$ is a permutation matrix.  See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5023#5023) for formatting matrices